# Visual studio 2013 not highlighting typescript file

Tags: colors, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am having a problem that Visual studio 2013 is showing all the text in a .ts file in black color. There are no colors for any of the code or comments. Am I missing a plugin or something? How can I get colors for ts files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the power tools : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/955e0262-0858-40c9-ab5a-1acc680e9bfd

More blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-typescript-1-3.aspx